# iOS remote notifications not showing outside app

Tags: ios, ios7, apple-push-notifications

The strangest thing has been bothering me for ages now. When sending a push notification from our sandbox environment the system receives the notification only when the app is in the foreground. Exiting the app and sending a push notification doesn't show a badge or alert.

These are the steps i've taken so far:

- Re-created the provisioning profile after generating the SSL.
- Made sure that the correct capabilities are in place.
- Verified that a device token is registered

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem here? Why would the push notification get received inside the app, but not outside?

Comment: check your notification tray. you get notification there. Check notification display setting in device settings.

Comment: If you mean the notification settings, then yes - that's on.

Comment: go to Settings > Notification Center > Your app > Alert Style.

Comment: This is not the issue. Notifications don't show with any of the available alert styles.